# swagger/openapi 3.0 how choose server from configured array in YML

Tags: swagger, openapi

i am using OpenApi 3.0. I have configured multiple servers in my YML-File and i am now wondering how to determine which one to use at runtime.

Is there a way to choose a server from the configured array, or do i have to use the setBasePath method of the ApiClient. AFAIK only the first one is hardcoded into the generated Stubs.

Can Anyone give me a hint?

regards Pascal

Comment: Do you mean client code generated by Swagger Codegen and if yes, which exactly language/framework?

Comment: Exactly, the code which is generated with the Swagger Codegen in Java. I mean it is possible to manually edit the basePath at runtime, but i am looking for for a more convenient way, i.e. choosing one of the configured paths in my YML

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue in the Swagger Codegen repository https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues.